# UIAlertController not appearing at all

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I am trying to add an `UIAlertController` to my app but it's not appearing at all. I have tried the following:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Web Service is not available." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
[alertController addAction:ok];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but this does not appear at all, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This code should work fine. Could you show us the rest of the context in which this snippet appears?

Comment: The code you've posted looks like it should work. What does your method look like that you're using to show that alert? Is that method getting called?

Comment: Are you trying to present this alert controller off of the main thread?  Are you even presenting it from a view controller?  Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In a storyboard's initial view controller, this has to be in `viewDidAppear:`. Otherwise if used in a XIB, it will also show an alert in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad`.

I ran your code in the Single View Application template in both iOS 8 and 9, putting your code into the given `ViewController,` in the following view life cycle callbacks:

- `viewDidAppear` - succeeded
- `viewWillAppear` - no alert shown; resulted in this output in the console: Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
- `viewDidLoad` - no alert shown; resulted in this output in the console: Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior ().

Comment: Why would you ever want to present an alert controller in viewDidLoad?  What if you're loading up a view but not necesarily presenting it?

Comment: To answer your first question, you may want to show an alert as soon as a view appears. However, I was simply mentioning that, in case Magna's code was in `viewDidLoad`. I just tried putting his code inside a `viewDidLoad` method in iOS 9 with a Storyboard (the Single View Application template), and I got an error: Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UIAlertController: 0x7ffa01d28ea0>). I'll expand my answer with some explanation.

Comment: viewDidLoad is not called as soon as the view appears.  That would be viewWillAppear.  And yes, it wouldn't make sense to present a view controller on a view while it is loading.

Comment: What I meant was that it is shown immediately. And, I don't think the question is about what makes sense. It is about getting an alert to show, using Apple's example from the UIAlertViewController reference.

Comment: i used same way but it not showing even viewdidappear() so is there any reason, we need display for restrict user may we call any where as we call uialertview any where any class or method why we not call this.???

Comment: Hi @khaskheli_ayaz, the only thing I can suggest is to pear down your view logic until it works, then add the logic until you see the offending code. It worked for me in the minimal case.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)showMessage:(BOOL)animated {

UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Do not leave any Field Empty"  message:nil  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}]];
[self present:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

where i call this method

```
        [self showMessage:YES];
```

it works fine may some one get benefits.